# Javascript - Date Validation IF Statement needed

Tags: javascript

So i wrote this part of an exercise already, but i need an IF statement using objects like "Date" and "dateOfBirth.getFullYear() == year" to validate that the user has entered a correct date. A simple solution would be very much appreciated. How do i put an IF statement in that will test if the user entered birthday is correct, and will reject if its false?

```
//Date Validation
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();

var phrase1;
phrase1 = "Name: ";

var name;
name = prompt( "Please enter your name:" );

var phrase2;
phrase2 = "<br />Mobile Number: ";

var mobile;
mobile = prompt( "Please enter your mobile number:" );

var phrase3;
phrase3 = "<br />E-mail Address: ";

var email;
email = prompt( "Please enter your E-mail Address:" );

var date;
date = prompt( "What day were you born on? e.g. 21st");
date = parseInt(date, 10);

var phrase4 = "<br /> Date of Birth: ";

var month;
month = prompt( "What month were you born in? e.g. April");

var phrase5 = " ";

var year;
year = prompt( "What year were you born in? e.g. 1996");

var phrase6 = " ";

var age;
var a = 2014;
var b = year;

age = a - b;

var phrase7 = "<br />Approximate Age: ";

var message;

message = phrase1 + name + phrase2 + mobile + phrase3 + email + phrase4 +        date + phrase5 + month + phrase6 + year + phrase7 + age;


canvas.drawString(message, 10, 10 );
canvas.setFont( "calibri", "16px", Font.ITALIC );
canvas.paint();
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: how do i put an IF statement in that will test if the user entered birthday is correct, and will reject if its false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkDate(date) {
   return new Date(date).getFullYear() == 2014
}

var date = null

while( ! checkDate(date)) {
    date = prompt('Please enter a date')
}

alert('Success, your date is: ' + date)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvfxwkzo/1/ (You should enter `2014-02-02`, for example)

Or, you can do it recursively:

http://jsfiddle.net/uvfxwkzo/2/

Comment: this work greats thanks but is it possible to change "You should enter 2014-02-02, for example" to "02-02-2014" format?

Comment: Yep, but in this case you should format it before the checking: http://jsfiddle.net/uvfxwkzo/3/

Comment: I'm sorry, previous example was incorrect, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/uvfxwkzo/4/

Comment: alright thanks for the help, but this "rejects" a date if its not in 2014, so how do I make it so it will accept any date as long as it isn't in the future? sorry if im asking too many questions

Comment: No problem, here is some example: http://jsfiddle.net/uvfxwkzo/5/. But if you want to go further, I highly recommend to use `momentjs`. I think it's the best library for working with dates (parse, compare, add, substract, etc)